# Why does theme I do not want to translate this word

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want to translate this word selected in img into French
in wordpress

[image]

I have used the plugin  loco translate but have not translated it
Iused theme WP residence

Answer (score 0):

For that theme, there are some words that can't be translated using the loco translate (or the PO files).

Go here and translate that word:

[image]

For more info on translating that theme, check this link:
[translate wp residence theme](http://help.wpresidence.net/article/translation/)

Comment: If i want translating  list word in features

Comment: it's the section above "Listings Labels", the "Features & Amenities".
Please accept the answer, it motivates people to answer questions.